# SSRS compatible shapefile​ for post codes?

Tags: shapefile, visualisation, reports

I am trying to make some data visual for a report to show how we are breaking up postcode regions.

I work at a university and we have a list of postcodes that we assign to campuses. I want to color the postcode regions on a map to a color representing the campus to make what area they cover visible.

I have found that SSRS has a map component, and that the Australian Bureau of Statistics releases post code shapefiles, but can't get the files to load in SSRS.

Would anyone know of a way to convert the shapefiles to get them working, or another way to get visualize this data?

Comment: Are you getting an error? Note that all files associated with the .shp are required. How are you loading them in SSRS? Have you followed the instructions [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/tutorial-map-report-report-builder)?

Answer (score 1):

Our BI department visualizes geometry with SRSS via native MS SQL spatial data (geometry data type in EPSG:2877).

You should load your .SHP into MS SQL geometry/geography data type, then point your SRSS report at that data.